# Conflict in Angular Request and getting Response from the server

Tags: angular, api, request, response, conflict

I have an Angular App and I Tried to get 4 requests from My API at the same times but sometimes all requests get the same result.
I tried a lot of things and check every endpoint without ant solutions
Could you please help how to solve this issue?
Thanks in Advance.
this is my code which describes the problem.

[image]

```js
     loadData(){
    this.servPrtner.GET(EndPointsURL.Partner).subscribe(
      (prtnr: ResponseDTO) => {
        if(prtnr.isPassed === true)
        {
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Checking...',
            text: prtnr.message,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            didOpen: () => {
              Swal.showLoading();
            },
          });
          this.partners = prtnr.data['list'];
          console.log(prtnr);
          Swal.close();
        }
        else
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'error',
          text: prtnr.message,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          didOpen: () => {
            Swal.showLoading();
          },
        });
        Swal.close();
        
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  };

loadData() {
    this.servconctent.GET(EndPointsURL.Content).subscribe((content: ResponseDTO) => {
      if (content.isPassed == true) {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Checking...',
          text: content.message,
          showConfirmButton: false,
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          didOpen: () => {
            Swal.showLoading();
          },
        });
        this.AllContent = content.data['list'];
        console.log(content);
        Swal.close();
      } else {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Error!',
          text: content.message,
          icon: 'error',
          confirmButtonText: 'Close',
          allowOutsideClick: false,
        });
      }
    },
      (error) => {
        Swal.fire({
          title: 'Error' + error.status,
          text: error.statusText,
          icon: 'error',
          confirmButtonText: 'Close',
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          didClose: () => {
            if (error.status === 401) {
              //this.http.setTokenExpiriation(true);
            }
          },
        });
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: I think it's a name conflict. Both functions are called loadData. Try changing the function names.

Comment: I tried to put all in one functions but the same result I will try your suggestions

Comment: No luck with this

Comment: Check endpoint URL in the network tab, whether the same endpoint is being called twice, if not check their result in the response tab

Comment: I did already and everything is perfect

Comment: have you tried using some rxjs operators ? check https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/merge

Comment: I tried it but still the same problem

Comment: any suggestions?